# Angular 6 Keyup auto currency

Tags: angular

I am trying to use keyup in an input element with currency pipe in Angular 8

```
<input placeholder="€0.00" (keyup)="onKey(pointIndex, $event.target.value, item.quantity)" value="{{item.unitPriceWithVat | currency:currency_code:'symbol-narrow':'1.2-2'}}"/>
```

When i write some number inside, it gets auto format into 200.00 or 1,230.00 ,  but the problem is if i try to write some number suppose 12,345.00 in the input it is formatting the number into something like this: 12.34

DEMO http://www.theme-oxygen.com/test/index.html

Can somebody help me to solve this problem!
Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: Could you share a demo using https://stackblitz.com/ ?

Comment: Hi the demo it s here  http://www.theme-oxygen.com/test/index.html try to write a price

Comment: What's your `keyup`? Could you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: You can see it in the Developer Console

Comment: @youri Hey i add the demo what example i need to provide

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `onKey` function, this line here:

```
let priceValue = parseFloat(price.replace(/[^0-9.,]+/g, ''));
```

`parseFloat` converts a value like `12,345.00` to `12`. You need to change this line to also replace the `,`.

```
let priceValue = parseFloat(price.replace(/[^0-9.]+/g, ''));
```